# How to add in angular ui-select custom option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ui-select

Have two ui-selects and changing only ng-model (data have from one mongodb collection):

```
<ui-select ng-model="flat.flatData.salesby" theme="bootstrap">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Sales by">
      {{ $select.selected.ag_name }}
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="uiag_name.ag_name as uiag_name in flat.ag track by $index | filter: $select.search">
     <div ng-bind-html="uiag_name.ag_name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

How can i add to the first ui-select option, for example 'option1', and to the second 'option2'?

Comment: you can get help from this url https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/152

Comment: i'm tryin' to do something like this, but ui-select-static-choice not working

Comment: uiSelectStaticChoice has not been implemented yet. So you can not use this. This is the proposal